# Import properties from spring-boot-dependencies pom without adding it as a parent

Tags: spring, maven

l am working with an existing multi-module project with many submodules. l would like to use the properties defined in the spring-boot-dependencies pom in the parent pom of this project, in order to keep dependencies of the subprojects in sync with the versions supported by spring.

l tried adding it as a parent pom of my project's parent pom, which does make the properties available but also imports the pluginManagement from that pom, which breaks the build. Is there any way to import only the properties from the spring pom into my parent pom, or any other place that l could import those properties from?

Comment: It would say no, as that is not how maven works. You could import it with `dependencyManagement` it will then manage the versions, but won't expose the properties.

Comment: If the usage as a parent breaks your build you might change your configuration and define all plugins etc. But in general you can't import only properties... you can use spring boot as so called BOM (dependencyManagement) that will make available all deps but does not use/import pluginManagement...